# I want to pass Date and Time I got using Datepicker Dialog and Timepicker Dialog to next Activity in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the Java code that Datepicker and Timepicker work. Those two are working properly so I want to send that selected date and time to the next activity(`Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page.java`)

```
 Doctor_Time_Picking_page.java
     public class Doctor_Time_Picking_page extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static final String TEXT_TO_SEND ="com.example.dogapp.TEXT_TO_SEND";
        private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
        private Button dateButton;
        private Button timeButton;
        private Bundle savedInstanceState;
        private Button saveButton;
        private String DATE;
    
    
        //On Create method-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_time_picking_page);
            initDatePicker();
            dateButton = findViewById(R.id.datePickerButton);
            timeButton = findViewById(R.id.timeButton);
            saveButton =  findViewById(R.id.date_time_save_button);
    
     
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page.class);
     
            saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    
    

        }
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private Bundle initDatePicker()
        {
    
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day)
                {
                    month = month + 1;
                    String date = makeDateString(day, month, year);
                   dateButton.setText(date);
    
    
    
                }
            };
    
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    
            int style = AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT;
    
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, style, dateSetListener, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    
            return null;
        }
    
        private String makeDateString(int day, int month, int year)
        {
            return getMonthFormat(month) + " " + day + " " + year;
        }
    
        private String getMonthFormat(int month)
        {
            if(month == 1)
                return "JAN";
            if(month == 2)
                return "FEB";
            if(month == 3)
                return "MAR";
            if(month == 4)
                return "APR";
            if(month == 5)
                return "MAY";
            if(month == 6)
                return "JUN";
            if(month == 7)
                return "JUL";
            if(month == 8)
                return "AUG";
            if(month == 9)
                return "SEP";
            if(month == 10)
                return "OCT";
            if(month == 11)
                return "NOV";
            if(month == 12)
                return "DEC";
            //default should never happen
            return "JAN";
        }
    
        public void openDatePicker(View view)
        {
            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    
    
    
    
        //Time Button
    
    
        int hour, minute;
    
    
        public void popTimePicker(View view)
        {
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
            {
    
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute)
                {
                    hour = selectedHour;
                    minute = selectedMinute;
                    timeButton.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d",hour, minute));
                }
            };
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, /*style,*/ onTimeSetListener, hour, minute, true);
    
            timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    
    
    }
```

---

This is the page where I want to show the date and Time selected form my previous activity(Doctor_Time_Picking_page.java)

`Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page.java`:
public class Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page extends AppCompatActivity {

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_time_picking_data_page);
    

            Button Button1a = findViewById(R.id.doc_page4_btn1);
            Button Button2a = findViewById(R.id.doc_page4_btn2);
            Button Button3a = findViewById(R.id.doc_page4_btn3);
            Dialog nDialog = new Dialog(this);
    
            
            Button1a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page.this,Doctor_Appoinment_payment.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    
            Button2a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page.this,Doctor_Time_Picking_page.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    
            Button3a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    nDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_delete_popup_msg);
                    nDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page.this,Doctor_delete_popup_msg.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    
        }
    }
```

In my project there are three buttons those are Select Time, Select Date and save button when I select each button Datepicker and Timepicker dialogues appear when I select Date or time those Data is appearing on the Buttons I want to pass those data to my next activity which is Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page.java and display them to user. What I now want is I want to pass That data selected from those Pickers to next activity

Comment: Ok. You told what you want. But you did not tell which problem(s) you have. What is wrong with your code? And we do not even know when and how you want to pass data.

Comment: @blackapps I guess he is going to pass data from the click of save button

Comment: The problem is I can't Send the date and time I selected from the pickers to the next Activity. I know I have to do it using Intent but I have no idea how to pass those 2 data

Comment: Why not make the string field date a public variable in the class and then pass it is an extra to the intent? If u don't know that, I can give an answer for that @Binusha

Comment: If you can give me answer It will helps me a lot @Sambhav. K

Comment: Thankyou,. I will wait@Sambhav.K

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an intent extra to the other activity to get your result. Follow the steps:

1. Create a filed name `date` in your class:

```java
private String date = "JAN 1 2022"; // I have given a sample date
```

2. You need to store the date inside the `DateSetListener` like this:

```java
 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day)
                {
                    month = month + 1;
                    date = makeDateString(day, month, year);
                    dateButton.setText(date);
    
    
    
                }
            };
```

2. You need to pass that date on the click of the save button:

```java
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    intent.putExtra("date", date);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

3. Then you need to get that date on the other activity like this:

```java
public class Doctor_Time_Picking_data_page extends AppCompatActivity {

        ...
 
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_time_picking_data_page);
    
               String date = getIntent().getStringExtra("date", "");
    
               //  that is the date from the previous activity
          
               ...
            });
            
            ...

    }
```

Comment: in the 2nd step that you said, 'DATA' is shown as "Cannot resolve symbol 'DATE'" I think That is Because the 1st Step is VOID. Can you give me a solution for that

Comment: Does the step 1 give any warning or error?

Comment: No, it doesn't show any error. In my code Step, 2 is 1st assigned and then Step 1 assigned after that

Comment: That is weird. Try to make the field `DATE` public

Comment: Yes. I saw the code. I will update my answer